# How to query all reports columns api names which has only columns using apex?

Tags: apex, developer

I am trying to fetch all reports columns api names which has more than 1 columns. If the report has no columns I need to put those report id in a separate List. Below is my code but still facing error "**Picklist value does not exist**" like this as some records has no columns.Can someone help me where did I go wrong?

```
    public class getRecordColumnNames {
    public static void getAllRecordsColumns(){
            for(Report rep : [SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName FROM Report]){
                String reportId = rep.Id;
                System.debug('reportId : '+reportId);
                Reports.ReportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId);
                Reports.ReportMetadata rm = results.getReportMetadata();
                System.debug('results :'+rm.getDetailColumns());
                if(rm.getDetailColumns().size() > 0){
                 System.debug('Detail columns: ' + rm.getDetailColumns() +'/n');
                }
                else{
                List<Id> reportIds = new List<Id>();
                reportIds.add(reportId);
                System.debug('reportIds without columns ' +reportIds);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```